# Mac Selectbox Problem

Tags: css, macos, drop-down-menu

Anyone Know How to change the Color of Selectbox in Mac.

Its Working Fine in Winows ad Also Mozilla in Mac

Its Does n't Work in Mac Chrome and Safari ?

Website : works.sodprojects.com/fitback/index.php

CAN ANYBODY HELP ME ??

Comment: I don't think this is possible...

Comment: Code? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? Is there any applicable documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom border:

```
border: 1px solid #444;
color: red;
```

This would show a select-box with a dark gray border and red text.